# Rails seed database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, seeding

I am trying to add a reviews table to my database, and seed some dummy data into the tables.

I can insert into the reviews table through `psql` command line but when seeding I get errors. Im not sure what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is my migration I ran

```
 class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
     t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
     t.references :product, index: true, foreign_key: true
     t.text :description
     t.integer :rating

     t.timestamps null: false
    end
   end
 end
```

This is the error I get when running `db:reset`

```
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
Finding or Creating REVIEWS ...
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Review:0x00000006feb4a0>
Did you mean?  user_id
```

This is my seed file

```
user1 = User.find_or_create_by! ({first_name: 'bob', last_name:'long', email: 'bob@email.com', password_digest: '1234'})

puts "Finding or Creating REVIEWS ..."

Review.destroy_all

user1.reviews.create!({
 product_id: 1,
 description: 'some text',
 rating: 3
})
```

My schema, seems to be fine and has both

`add_index "reviews",["product_id"],name:"index_reviews_on_product_id",using: :btree`
  `add_index "reviews",["user_id"],name:"index_reviews_on_user_id",using: :btree`

as well as having both

`add_foreign_key "reviews", "products"`
  `add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"`

Here is my review model

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :product

 validates :product, presence: true
 validates :user, presence: true
 validates :rating, presence: true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `belongs_to :user` to your review model.

Comment: Your right, that was the problem. Thanks, really appreciate it!